# PHP - Appending to array within a loop

Tags: php, arrays

How do I append elements to an array within a loop? For example, I am using a library to render a graph.

I wish to add values to the graph like so:

```
$data = array();

for ($x=0; $x<=50; $x++)
{
    $data["00:".x] = rand(-10, 30);
}
```

So in theory I should have the elements "00:00", "00:01", "00:02" etc. all with a random number as their value. However, the library does not then render the graph.

I'm guessing it's because I don't understand PHP enough. How do I go about trying to achieve this?

Comment: You should add `error_reporting(-1);` to enable proper debugging; also consider adding `var_dump($data);` to see where things went wrong.

Comment: I did not know about those, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the leading zeros for values of `$x` 0 through 9. You're also missing the dollar sign before your variable `$x`:

```
for ($x=0; $x<=50; $x++)
{
    $data["00:".str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)] = rand(-10, 30);
}
```